# How do I jitter just the outliers in a ggplot boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am using `geom_jitter()` for a boxplot with ggplot. I noticed it adds a point for every record on top of the boxplot, instead of jittering just the points that represent outliers.

This is demonstrated by this code.

```
data <- as.data.frame(c(rnorm(10000, mean = 10, sd = 20), rnorm(300, mean = 90, sd = 5)))
names(data) <- "blapatybloo"

data %>% ggplot(aes("column", blapatybloo)) + geom_boxplot() + geom_jitter(alpha=.1)
```

How do I apply `geom_jitter` to only the points on the boxplot without overlapping the rest of the records?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new column to determine if a data point is an outlier or not. 
Then overlay the points onto the boxplot.

```
data <- as.data.frame(c(rnorm(10000, mean = 10, sd = 20), 
                        rnorm(300, mean = 90, sd = 5))) 

names(data) <- "blapatybloo"

data <- data %>% 
               mutate(outlier = blapatybloo > median(blapatybloo) + 
               IQR(blapatybloo)*1.5 | blapatybloo < median(blapatybloo) -
               IQR(blapatybloo)*1.5) 

data %>% 
       ggplot(aes("column", blapatybloo)) + 
       geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
       geom_point(data = function(x) dplyr::filter(x, outlier), 
                  position = "jitter")
```

Comment: Great. And then adding `"column"` as the x-value was my work around to the `Error: stat_boxplot requires the following missing aesthetics: y`. Is there a more standard solution?

Comment: Can I control the width and height of the jitter when it's geom_point getting used?

Comment: Not sure, you can just put in `''` instead of `"column"` to get a similar solution

Comment: `geom_point` uses `position = jitter`, you can use `height = ` and `width = ` as extra arguments to control those variables.

Comment: I looked and it said filter_ is depreciated. Is there a way to do this with `data = filter(outliers == TRUE)`?

Comment: I tried and received `Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: height` `Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: width`

Comment: Apologies for late response. Instead of `filter_(x, ~ outlier)` you can use `filter(x, outlier)`. I have updated my response above.

Comment: @Cauder Regarding your first comment about `Error: stat_boxplot requires the following missing aesthetics: y`; boxplots show the distribution of values along the y axis. The x axis is for stratifying across different groups, for example.